React id swiper is not working in React 18
I am using react 18 with Swiper version ^11.1.3 and  react-id-swiper with version ^4.0.0.When I am trying to use this,I get this error.
"Missing "./css/swiper.css" specifier in "swiper" package"
I have inlcluded this css file in my component...
import 'swiper/css/swiper.css';

In Swiper version 11.1.3, the import path for the CSS file has been updated. Instead of import swiper/css/swiper.css, you should use:
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';

This is working, I mean no error is there but the problem is the 3d coverflow effect is not working
I am using these params
const params={     effect: "coverflow",     grabCursor: true,     centeredSlides: true,     slidesPerView: "auto",     coverflowEffect: {       rotate: 50,       stretch: 0,       depth: 100,       modifier: 1,       slideShadows: true     },     pagination: {       el: ".swiper-pagination"     }   }
